# SSRS 2016 Report Manager screen hanging on "Loading...." when creating a subscription to a report

Tags: ssrs-2016

I am planning a migration to 2016 Reporting Services and have noticed a particular problem. On two separate new installs for SSRS 2016 Developer Edition, I am unable to save a subscription to a report. The report was downloaded as RDL from the current 2008 R2 server, then saved to the new 2016 environment. The new server is build 13.0.4466.4. I also installed the same version of SQL onto a second server and have reproduced this problem. All servers are running in Native Mode.

Within Report Manager, I am able to view the contents of the report (on-demand). When I try to create a subscription, the web page is stuck with the "Loading...." prompt after I click 'Create subscription'. It does this regardless of the Render Format I choose. I am attempting to deliver via e-mail. I have domain credentials for the SSRS service account configured, and I have put the IP address for the SMTP server in RS Configuration Manager, so I know it is configured for email ok.

In the SSRS log file, I see these types of errors at the time I try to create the subscription:

```
    library!ReportServer_0-1!2888!03/06/2018-16:19:17:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: The requested functionality is not currently enabled.;
extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-1!2888!03/06/2018-16:19:17:: i INFO: Skipped instantiating Report Server PowerBI report server extension. Extension was not enabled.
library!ReportServer_0-1!2888!03/06/2018-16:19:17:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.OperationNotSupportedNativeModeException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.OperationNotSupportedNativeModeException: This operation is not supported on a report server that runs in native mode.;
library!ReportServer_0-1!2668!03/06/2018-16:19:18:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: The requested functionality is not currently enabled.;
extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-1!2668!03/06/2018-16:19:18:: i INFO: Skipped instantiating Report Server PowerBI report server extension. Extension was not enabled.
library!ReportServer_0-1!2bf0!03/06/2018-16:19:18:: i INFO: Call to GetPermissionsAction(/Pre-Migration/Open Activity Report). User: XXXX\xxx.
library!WindowsService_0!2518!03/06/2018-16:24:35:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch()
```

In the Windows Application log, I see these events repeated:

```
(Event ID 137)
The Report Server PowerBI extension failed to read its configuration settings from the RSReportServer.config configuration file. The extension is not available to users.
```

PowerBI Integration is not enabled on either of the 2016 servers, and is obviously not a part of the existing 2008 R2 configuration. I do not wish to use this feature.

How do I solve this problem and begin to create subscriptions, so I can ultimately migrate all of the reports?

Comment: After the initial posting, I was able to determine that if I connect to Report Manager from either IE11 on that server, or from IE11 on another server, the functionality would work perfectly. Something was different: either with the particular build of IE I had, group policy settings, or some other arcane IE setting. We did determine that the compatibility level for the browser needs to be at least at v. 10. For some reason our PCs are set to v. 5. Security told me that SSRS may allow the server to specify the level for the clients. I will update further  when there is a determination.